# Accessing claims from ProfileService

Tags: identityserver4

I have a simple project with identityserver4 and ElmahCore.
I added a custom IProfileService and IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
Authentication works like a charm, but custom claims I add in the Profile Service do not show up in the principal when I try to restrict Elmah access.

```
services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(
    options => {
        options.CheckPermissionAction = context => context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
);
```

The User Identity exists and is authenticated, but the only claims that exist are `sub`, `name`, `auth_time`, `idp` and `amr`. 
Other custom claims do not show up.

The value of sub is set to the value I expect it to have.

I also added this line before calling `services.AddIdentityServer()`, but nothing changed:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<HaproUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

The application configuration is set up like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(
        new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        }
    );
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    app.UseElmah();
}
```

And service configurations is this:

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<HaproUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.AddProfileService<HaproProfileService>();
builder.AddResourceOwnerValidator<HaproPasswordValidator>();


if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
```

The ProfileService is fairly straight forward:

```
public class HaproProfileService : IProfileService
{
    // IsActiveAsync omitted

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var claims = context.RequestedClaimTypes.Select(type => MapClaim(type, user)).ToList();

        context.AddRequestedClaims(claims);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private static Claim MapClaim(string type, HaproUser user)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "name":
                return new Claim(type, user.DisplayName);

            // Omitted cases here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does your profile service look like?

Comment: The profile service works fine when calling the identityserver from an external client application, but it just generetates a `List<Claim>` and calls `context.AddRequestedClaims(claims)`